# CSS Generic vs Page Specific loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some advice on CSS placements for the sake of website load times

I read that it's best to have 'critical CSS' in the head and the rest can be placed in their respective page's body via the  tag.

Is it good practice if I loaded all the CSS or at least the 'Generic' styles that many pages share while I kept page specific styles in a  tag in the page's body?

One side question, some of my pages use jQuery, should I only load that at the bottom of those pages or leave it in the template head?

I tried both and the site loads just fine, but I know under the hood results may vary. I'm not sure how to even check. I tried websites that test a website's load performance and I got mixed results. So I'm not sure how to optimize my website's performance.

Comment: You can use lighthouse (in chromium developer menu) to do a quick benchmark on your page's loadtime, if you get 10/10, you don't really need to do anything, otherwise, lighthouse gives you a lot of tips.
The most important thing is to use as little css/js/libraries as possible as loading these files only becomes an actuall problem when you have thousands upon thousands of lines (eg discord)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually all CSS files are called in the head, one thing you can do to improve performance is to modularize, let's say that you have the *global* styles in one file called `global.css` and it contains your font specs, global components used in all pages such as navbar, footer, layouts, etc... And in another file you can only put the styles regarding your specified page such as *contact section* that's another page called `contact.css` and there you can have overrides to global file and specific styles that you *only* use in this page.

This way you can serve less heavy files regarding the page that user's requiring.

Regarding you jQuery question I suggest that don't load jQuery library if you're not using it, it's useless. Only load it in the pages that you're using the library. Hope it helps!